# CSS - How to center nested divs?

Tags: css, html, centering

New to CSS.

I am trying to center nested divs using the code below

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="formpanel">
                <div id="loginForm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background : #90ADB7 url('images/background.png') repeat-x;
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.85em;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style:solid;
    padding: 190px 0;
}

#formpanel {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: auto;
}

#loginForm {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

the problem is that the innermost div (#loginForm) flushes with the top edge of the outer div (#formpanel). How should I center the inner div ?

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Since @BillyMoon's answer from 2011 is in the delete queue, here's the link he originally posted: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use relative positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/a879W/

Comment: Thanks. This works. Also thanks for jsfiddle. Didn't know about this tool.

Comment: for posterity: #loginForm {
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    top:25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color:blue;
}

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works when width <= 100% - but what about width > 100%?

Answer (score 2):

```
#formpanel {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

#loginForm {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#loginForm {
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

EDIT: top: 25% not 50%.

Comment: Nice one, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @Jivings, this doesn't work. are you sure about position:absolute ?

Comment: Sorry, you need position relative on the containing component as well.

Answer (score 1):

//CSS code (index.css)

```
.outer{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: auto;
}
.middle{
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

//html code (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="inner"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning:

```
#formpanel {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
}

#loginForm {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: And if the window is resized? Absolute positioning is no good for centering components.

Comment: I assumed, since the wrapper div has a fixed width, there should be no need to resize the window...